# After running the Version Changes tool ..Export pre-reconcile/post records from parent

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I would like to export those records identified as changes after running the Version Changes tool before running Reconcile and Post tools.  Preferably with python or having python call a program to do the export of the Version Changes records to somewhere and then continue on with an automated reconcile/post process.  But any solution would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find Version Changes between two Versions, all you have to do is use a [DifferenceCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000021t000000.htm). This is how any difference between versions (for example, detecting conflicts) is implemented internally. Make sure you open the tables that you pass in from the right version - people tend to make that mistake.

Comment: trust me, I know this will work :) haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to either add some data to your feature class or utilize the sde versioning tables to select the correct records.
I have seen systems utilize an update record date field. But you would need to manage that in your db or your work flow.
The sde versioning tables keep track of the adds, deletes, and updates (add/delete).
As for the automation of this I am helpless.
Have you spent any time on the edn website?
The resource page has a good [101 document](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0408/entergdb_101.html)
[EDNDoc](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/GeoDatabase_overview.htm) has some good info.
 I think I did see a HasEdits that might help.
I did just read @mapperz response, but will leave these links as they are harder and harder to find these days.
I just noticed the show extent of modified objects code at the very bottom of link 2

Answer (score -1):

This question is answered here:
[Creating Python script to reconcile/post geodatabase versions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/is-it-possible-to-create-a-python-script-to-rec-post-versions)

debate:close this question?

Comment: Automating rec/post != exporting changes before rec/post.

Comment: @Swingley hence the option "debate" -  can vote to close but chose not to because of the wording.

Comment: @Mapperz- My take is that this is a different question, I would not vote to close.

Comment: I downvoted, as it is clear to me it is a different question than the one in the link and it is not answered there (and in my opion it is a far more interesting question, but that's only my opinion).